# Some exercises about Galois Groups and Automorphisms of a finite field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

Hey I have these two exercises where I am having some problems solving them:

Let $E/K$ be a finite field extension, let $G$ be a subgroup of $Aut(E/K)$. Show:

a) $G$ is finite and $|G|$ is a divisor of $[E : K]$.
b) Exactly then $|G| = [E : K]$ if $E/K$ is Galois with $G =Gal(E/K)$.

For a) I have:

Since $|G|\leq |Aut(E/K)|\leq[E:K]$, $G$ is finite. $G$ is a subgroup of $Aut(E/K)$, therefore $|G|$ divides $|Aut(E/K)|$. Since for every $\tau \in Aut(E/K), \tau(K)=K$ every $\tau$ is just a permutation on the elements of $E\K$ therefore the number of the elements divides $[E:K]$. From this follows our assumption.

Here I am not sure if I have done any mistake.

For b) I have only one direction of the implication: $|G| = [E : K]$ $\Leftrightarrow$  $E/K$ is Galois with $G =Gal(E/K)$

$\Rightarrow$: Since $|G|\leq |Aut(E/K)|\leq[E:K]$ so we have $|Aut(E/K)|=[E:K]$ and therefore is $E/K$ Galois with $G =Gal(E/K)$.

For $\Leftarrow$ I really dont know what to do. Can someone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "the roots of $E/K$"? I don't get your solution to the second part of $(a)$. In part $(b)$, in the first direction you showed that $E/K$ is a Galois extension, and $|G|=|\text{Gal}(E/K)|$, but didn't explain why the two groups are equal. It follows immediately because there is inclusion, but it's still better to mention it. And I'm sorry, but the other direction is trivial. Try to think about it a bit more. I don't see any way to give a hint that will not be the full solution.

Comment: About your attempt at part (a): What are *the roots of $E/K$*? I have never heard of such a term. Also, there are groups of permutations of order three on a set of four elements.

Comment: You actually need a non-trivial result of Galois theory to handle part (a). One that deals with fixed fields of groups of automorphisms to be a bit more precise. Look for one such in the course material. Missus calling, and I gotta go. Mark is very capable of helping you here.

Comment: The result mentioned by @JyrkiLahtonen is usually used while proving the fundamental theorem of Galois theory. That should be a big hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your proof of (a) past the part where you show inequality.

For (a), we have $E^G$, the fixed field of G, gives a Galois extension $E/E^G$ with Galois group $G$. Thus, $|G| = [E : E^G]$. Note that $K \subseteq E^G$. I'll leave it to you to complete the argument from here. It's a simple degree argument.

For the converse of (b), you should review the several equivalent definitions of a Galois extension. It follows rather directly from the extension being Galois.